# Why MySQL IF(0 = 'foo', 1, 2) resolves in 1, i.e. string equals 0

Tags: mysql, if-statement

This must have been documented and asked before, but I can't seem to find any sensible information about it.

**Short version/actual problem**

When creating a MySQL procedure the following resolves as true:

`IF(0 = 'foo', 1, 2) /* resolves in 1 */`

Though the string 'foo' isn't equal to 0.

The following query resolves as not true:

`IF(1 = 'foo', 1, 2) /* resolves in 2 */`

Which makes sense, since the string 'foo' isn't equal to 1.

How come might this be?

**Practical use case**

I have a column which allows null values. Sometimes this column should hold the value 0. Due to the way data comes in from the API, empty string should write `NULL` in the column and `0` should write 0.

The procedure that handles the data uses the following IF functions to handle these cases:

`IF(variable="", NULL, variable)`

If the `variable = 0` the above produces `NULL` as opposed to the expected `0`.

Comment: numerical variable should not be null (as well as non-numerical variable should not be 0). I would say that API has been designed in a somewhat poor way if it allows otherwise

Comment: @mangusta why a numerical variable shouldn't be `null`? It's perfectly legit

Comment: @Cid it might be legit but allowing numerical and non-numerical data types for the same parameter makes API overcomplicated, degrades readability and negatively affects maintenance

Comment: by "should not be null" I meant the data type in the api itself, not the way it is stored in the table

Comment: @mangusta that's was my question. Why a numerical value couldn't be null in an API? How would you treat the case there are no values actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few stages you need to understand here. The left hand side of the expression determines what type would be used to do the comparison, and the right hand side gets converted to that type. So far, it's pretty intuitive. The next step may be less intuitive - MySQL can implicitly convert a string to a number, even if the string **does not represnt a number**. It does so by taking any character it can use (i.e., a leading `-`, digits, one decimal point) and converting them to a number, and then silently ignoring any following characters. `'foo'` has no characters that can be converted to a number, so it's implicitly converted to a zero.

Comment: Thanks for the information!

With that logic, though, shouldn't `IF('foo' = 0, ...)` be valid in that case? That seeing how the left hand side determines the type, so 0 should be converted into a string and as such the expression should be false, no?